# KivyMD android application crashing at startup

Tags: python, android, kivy, kivymd

My application built with KivyMD crashes when start on Android, while it works properly when the .py file is run.
I looked online and there are many reports of this issue, but none of the solutions solved my problem (they helped me though).

I am currently using the following external modules specified in the *requirements.txt* file:

`crayion.py, kivy, kivymd, buildozer, pytest`

crayion.py has only *requests* as its own dependency

Using a little bit of trial and error and adb debug on the crash, I ended up adding this requirement line in the buildozer.spec file (whenever the log told me that one of these modules was missing, I added it):

```
requirements = python3,kivy==master,craiyon.py,kivymd==1.1.1,docutils,sdl2_ttf==2.0.15,pil,requests,urllib3,idna,chardet,Image,pysocks,aiohttp,multidict,attrs,certifi,pygments,pypiwin32,yarl,async-timeout,charset-normalizer,cchardet
```

At this point the error I receive is not a *missing module* error, but this:

```
02-13 18:40:24.128  2022 17111 I python  :   File "/github/workspace/src/dreamvision/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/build/python-installs/dreamvision/arm64-v8a/aiohttp/client_reqrep.py", line 70, in <module>
02-13 18:40:24.129  2022 17111 I python  :   File "/github/workspace/src/dreamvision/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/build/python-installs/dreamvision/arm64-v8a/cchardet/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
02-13 18:40:24.129  2022 17111 I python  : ImportError: dlopen failed: "/data/data/com.aidreamvision.dreamvision/files/app/_python_bundle/site-packages/cchardet/_cchardet.so" is for EM_X86_64 (62) instead of EM_AARCH64 (183)
02-13 18:40:24.129  2022 17111 I python  :
02-13 18:40:24.129  2022 17111 I python  : During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
02-13 18:40:24.129  2022 17111 I python  :
02-13 18:40:24.129  2022 17111 I python  : Traceback (most recent call last):
02-13 18:40:24.129  2022 17111 I python  :   File "/github/workspace/src/dreamvision/.buildozer/android/app/main.py", line 9, in <module>
02-13 18:40:24.129  2022 17111 I python  :   File "/github/workspace/src/dreamvision/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/build/python-installs/dreamvision/arm64-v8a/craiyon/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
02-13 18:40:24.129  2022 17111 I python  :   File "/github/workspace/src/dreamvision/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/build/python-installs/dreamvision/arm64-v8a/craiyon/craiyon.py", line 2, in <module>
02-13 18:40:24.130  2022 17111 I python  :   File "/github/workspace/src/dreamvision/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/build/python-installs/dreamvision/arm64-v8a/aiohttp/__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
02-13 18:40:24.130  2022 17111 I python  :   File "/github/workspace/src/dreamvision/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/build/python-installs/dreamvision/arm64-v8a/aiohttp/client.py", line 59, in <module>
02-13 18:40:24.130  2022 17111 I python  :   File "/github/workspace/src/dreamvision/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/build/python-installs/dreamvision/arm64-v8a/aiohttp/client_reqrep.py", line 72, in <module>
02-13 18:40:24.130  2022 17111 I python  :   File "/github/workspace/src/dreamvision/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/build/python-installs/dreamvision/arm64-v8a/charset_normalizer/__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
02-13 18:40:24.130  2022 17111 I python  :   File "/github/workspace/src/dreamvision/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/build/python-installs/dreamvision/arm64-v8a/charset_normalizer/api.py", line 5, in <module>
02-13 18:40:24.131  2022 17111 I python  :   File "/github/workspace/src/dreamvision/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/build/python-installs/dreamvision/arm64-v8a/charset_normalizer/cd.py", line 9, in <module>
02-13 18:40:24.131  2022 17111 I python  : ImportError: dlopen failed: "/data/data/com.aidreamvision.dreamvision/files/app/_python_bundle/site-packages/charset_normalizer/md.so" is for EM_X86_64 (62) instead of EM_AARCH64 (183)
```

where to me it sounds as if the modules I am trying to use are not built for the right architecture, from this line: **ImportError: dlopen failed: "/data/data/com.aidreamvision.dreamvision/files/app/_python_bundle/site-packages/charset_normalizer/md.so" is for EM_X86_64 (62) instead of EM_AARCH64 (183)**

any advice on how to solve this?
I have been trying for days and tried to apply actions from hundreds of similar emails.

For more context I can provide the link to the github repository where I am working, but I don't know if this is allowed and helpful.

Comment: Ok, I figured out this particular problem from the instructions on Python 4 android library and I had to use a specific version of charset_normalizer: `charset_normalizer==2.1.1`. Now I am getting another problem: the app continues crashing, and I am recieving a new error every time with a new module, I added more than 10 new modules and the list is not ending

Comment: In case that can be helpful to anyone, I managed to solve by importing all the 2nd tier and 3rd tier dependencies from the Github dependency page of my project. Not sure about how to decide which ones were needed and which weren't, but this ultimately worked